# Remove Specific row Apache Poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need to remove row that contains word that user inputs. Here my code:

```
        try {
            System.out.println("Write material that need to be removed: ");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            String toFind = in.nextLine();
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("solty.xls"));

            //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
            DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            for (Row row : sheet) {
                for (Cell cell : row) {
                    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

                    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                        Row row3 = rowIterator.next();
                        CellReference cellRef = new CellReference(row3.getRowNum(), cell.getColumnIndex());
                        
                        String text = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);

                        // is it an exact match?
                        if (toFind.equals(text)) {
                            System.out.println("Text finded at " + cellRef.formatAsString());
                            System.out.println(cellRef.getRow());
                            int rowIndex = cellRef.getRow();
                            System.out.println(row.getCell(rowIndex));
                            HSSFRow row1 = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
                            sheet.removeRow(row1);
                            file.close();
                            FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("solty.xls"));
                            workbook.write(outFile);
                            outFile.flush();
                            outFile.close();

                        }
                        // is it a partial match?
                        else if (text.contains(toFind)) {
                            System.out.println("Index is  " + cellRef.formatAsString());


                        }


                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but the problem is that it deletes row consistently, not the row that contains user's word. Also even it works it has Exception : ConcurrentModificationException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown because `Sheet.removeRow` tries to change a row while a `Iterator` iterates over the rows of that sheet. This is not possible.

So instead of using `Iterator` you need to get the rows another way. For example use `for` loop using `int r` and `sheet.getRow(r)` to get the rows.

But `Sheet.removeRow` has a misleading name. It does not really removing a row but only removes the row from the sheet's storage without shifting the rows below upwards. So in fact it only totally empties the row. If you really wants removing the row, you need using `Sheet.shiftRows`. `Sheet.shiftRows` had many bugs in former versions of `apache poi`. So it only will work properly using current `apache poi 5.0.0`.

But using `Sheet.shiftRows` each shifting will influence the row numbers. So the `for` loop using `int r` and `sheet.getRow(r)` to get the rows needs to loop backwards from bottom to top, else it will try to get row numbers which were removed already.

The following code should work using current `apache poi 5.0.0` and removing all rows containing cells having `String toFind` as content.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

class RemoveSpecificRows {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     
  System.out.println("Write material that need to be removed: ");
  java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
  String toFind = in.nextLine();

  try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelSource.xls")); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("ExcelResult.xls") ) {

   DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
   
   Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
   
   for (int r = sheet.getLastRowNum(); r >=0;  r--) {
    Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
    if (row != null) {
     for (int c = 0; c < row.getLastCellNum(); c++) {
      Cell cell = row.getCell(c);
      String value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
      if (toFind.equals(value)) {
       System.out.println("Text " + toFind + " found at " + cell.getAddress()); 
       //sheet.removeRow(row); //this only empties the row
       sheet.shiftRows(r + 1, sheet.getLastRowNum() + 2, -1); //shift row below up to last row once up
       break;
      }
     }
    }      
   }

   workbook.write(fileout);

  }

 }
}
```

Comment: Bro, you literally saved my life. Thank you so much. I can't solve this problem for one week!

Comment: and one more question. How I can now this removed row insert into another Excel document?

Comment: please, can you help here?

Comment: @senseiton: No. At first this would must be asked as another question in StackOverflow. And at second it is not possible in my opinion that general. Rows and cells are related to their sheet and workbook in many terms. So to get a row from one sheet an then put that row into another sheet is not simply possible. It tends to be impossible if that sheet additional is in a different workbook.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67251536/insert-removed-row-into-another-xls-file       so I asked it as another q