# Insert removed row into another xls file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

@AxelRichter had helped me how to delete row in `WorkBook`, but now i need to insert this removed row at another `xls` file. How can i make this?

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

class RemoveSpecificRows {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     
  System.out.println("Write material that need to be removed: ");
  java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
  String toFind = in.nextLine();

  try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelSource.xls")); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("ExcelResult.xls") ) {

   DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
   
   Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
   
   for (int r = sheet.getLastRowNum(); r >=0;  r--) {
    Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
    if (row != null) {
     for (int c = 0; c < row.getLastCellNum(); c++) {
      Cell cell = row.getCell(c);
      String value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
      if (toFind.equals(value)) {
       System.out.println("Text " + toFind + " found at " + cell.getAddress()); 
       //sheet.removeRow(row); //this only empties the row
       sheet.shiftRows(r + 1, sheet.getLastRowNum() + 2, -1); //shift row below up to last row once up
       break;
      }
     }
    }      
   }

   workbook.write(fileout);

  }

 }
}
```

output file is `sale.xls` , input is `solty.xls`

Comment: So have you tried editing your code so instead of removing the target row, it cuts then selects the other file and pastes? Have a go then come back with what you have attempted and then you may get more help.

Comment: I've searched a lot of information, but I can't find solution

Comment: It is not possible to take a `Row` from one sheet and put it into another because the `Row` is related to its `Sheet` and to its `Workbook`. What one can do is to get all cell values from a row and then set those values into cells of a row in another sheet. But if cell formatting and/or formulas also needs to be copied, then it will get very complex and complicated and much too broad for an answer here. So your question is too general. It needs to be more focused.

Comment: well, so how can I can copy cell? it's my coursework so I have about 20 hours to done this and i have no clue how to do this... @AxelRichter